# Saving Dataset in Hive as avro format merge column

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, avro

I try to put in hive in avro format, data from dataset. but each column in my dataset is merged into one in the hive table.

```
Dataset<obj1> = ....

Dataset<obj1>.printSchema();

root
 |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: string (nullable = true)
 |-- e: string (nullable = true)
```

Save the dataset in Hive :

```
Dataset<obj1>.write()
              .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
              .partitionBy("a")
              .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
              .option("recordName", "recordName_custom")
              .option("recordNamespace", "recordNamespace_custom")
              .saveAsTable("DB.TABLE");
```

result of the table created in hive :

```
show create table DB.TABLE;
```

result :

```
    CREATE TABLE `DB.TABLE`( 
    `col` array<string> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
    PARTITIONED BY (                                   
       `a` string)
...
```

At the moment, one of the solution is to put dataset as avro file into HDFS :

```
  Dataset<obj1>
        .write()
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .partitionBy("a")
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
        .option("recordName", "recordName_custom")
        .option("recordNamespace", "recordNamespace_custom")
        .save("path");
```

then create a external table to it.
at the end of the batch, we do a MSCK REPAIR to detect new partition if needed.

any solution, best practice advise ?

Version used:

com.databricks, spark-avro_2.11: 4.0.0
Spark: 2.3.2
Hadoop: 2.3.2
HDFS: 3.1.1.3.1
Hive: 3.1.0